# Mysql REGEXP for username

Tags: mysql, regex

what is Mysql query REGEXP to call this?

```
@text
@user_name
@4ll_r1ght
@last2
@_last1
@and1more_
```

Comment: what you want to do? specify in details.

Comment: hi Gaurav, i just need REGEXP to call records that contains '@', text, numbers, and underscore (random order like my question above)

Comment: are you fetching the data from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username REGEXP '^\@[0-9a-zA-Z_]+$'
```

Will select users with usernames starting with `@` and consisting of only alphanumeric characters (at least one).

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking for regular expression for username with specified characters.

Try below :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@
```

This part of the expression validates the ‘username’ section of the email address. The hat sign (^) at the beginning of the expression represents the start of the string.

If we didn’t include sign (^), then someone could key in anything they wanted before the email address and it would still validate.

Here, we are allowing the letters a-z, A-Z, the numbers 0-9, and the symbols underscore (_), period (.), and dash (-). You can add/remove them according to your needs.